# Brew Edit OpenCV Package Source and Recompile

Tags: python, c++, git, opencv, homebrew

I installed OpenCV 2.4.12 through homebrew. There was a problem with the source code and I found a patch online. I don't believe OpenCV has officially supported the patch on git, so I was hoping to apply the modification by changing a few lines of code in one of the source files and just reinstall it.

The thing is, it doesn't seem like brew saves the source files anywhere. I tried installing from source using brew, as well as trying to unpack, edit the source in the unpacked files, and then reinstall, but nothing seems to work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "Nothing seems to work" is not a problem description. Anyhow, the right way is to write your own [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md). You may inspire yourself by the [default one](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/opencv.rb)

Comment: How can I edit that file to include a source code modification I made